# CqlSession cannot connect to Azure Cosmos DB Cassandra

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

I have this code

```java
@Bean
public CqlSession getCqlSession() {
    return CqlSession.builder()
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(cassandraHost, cassandraPort))
            .withAuthCredentials(cassandraUsername, cassandraPassword)
            .build();
}
```

The connection is failing with this exception:

```
Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'getCqlSession' threw
exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach 
any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors()
for more): Node(endPoint=tinyurl-cassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com/52.230.23.170:10350, hostId=null,
hashCode=237f706): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: [s0|control|id: 0xb89dacff,
L:/192.168.0.101:59158 - R:tinyurl-cassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com/52.230.23.170:10350] Protocol
initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): timed out after 5000 ms]
```

I am new to Cassandra and have tried the following:

1. Validated that the credentials are okay.
2. Try with `csqlsh` - could not connect as well.
3. Check there's no firewall setup in my machine. Can telnet to host and port.
4. Can open Cassandra Shell from Azure Data Explorer.

What am I missing? I am new to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the v.4x version of the Java Driver. The default load balancing in this driver mandates that you provide local data center, e.g:

```
            CqlSession.builder().withSslContext(sc)
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(cassandraHost, cassandraPort)).**withLocalDatacenter("UK South")**
            .withAuthCredentials(cassandraUsername, cassandraPassword).build();
```

You could take a look at this getting started sample for further reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-cassandra-java-getting-started-v4